# How do I keep a nonexistent work ID from breaking an API query?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am querying the Azure DevOps API to return data for several work items at a time.  The basic query is:

```
https://dev.azure.com/<organization>/_apis/wit/workitems/?ids=1234,2345,3456&api-version=6.0
```

But if one of those is not a valid work item ID, it returns something like this within the JSON response:

```
"message":"TF401232: Work item 3456 does not exist, or you do not have permissions to read it."
```

To me it seems like a better response would be the normal multi-ID JSON object with that message as one of many work item ID responses, instead of letting an invalid response break the entire query.  Is there any way to do that?  I haven't found any argument that seems to accomplish that, but I could easily have missed it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `errorPolicy` query flag in the api url. Set `errorPolicy` to `Omit`. See below:

`https://dev.azure.com/<organization>/_apis/wit/workitems/?ids=1234,2345,3456&errorPolicy=Omit&api-version=6.0`

When you use`errorPolicy=Omit` query flag. The nonexistent work item id will not break the API call. It will be omitted in the response instead.

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#uri-parameters) for more URI Parameters.

Comment: Thank you.  That works very well for my use case.  I somehow completely missed that.